Cisco ASA IKEv2+IPSec Remote Access VPN
Objective: Use ASA to support native VPN client for RA on current versions of Android, Windows 10/11 (and possibly others) using supported types such as IKEv2/IPSec+EAP/MSCHAPv2 for authentication.
An ASA (ASA5516/9.12) is currently used for IKEv1/LT2P Remote Access and IKEv1/IPSec L2L's, working well. It now needs to support IKEv2/IPSec for RA, as Android has removed support for LT2P (others will likely follow). If possible, would like to avoid using AnyConnect, SSL-based or any non-free client software. Would also prefer to use existing local usernames on ASA for authentication as done now with the IKEv1/LT2P, though (as far as I can tell) certificates are also required for IKEv2. Finally, IKEv1/LT2P and IKEv1/IPSec L2L also needs to continue to work.
I have not found online references or articles that specifically address this use case, though this one that describes IKEv2/EAP RA with Windows native is the closest (however the configuration examples are a bit incomplete). This one covers IKEv2 RA, but is for IOS.
Short version:
There is a CA certificate and a cert for both the ASA and an Android client. Using the native client with IKEv2/IPSec MSCHAPv2, gets as far as "Failed to locate an item in the database". My understanding of this is that it is failing to match the client to a tunnel-group - though there is both a tunnel group called VPNGRP and DefaultRAGroup (which I thought it would fall through to in this case). I had thought that the ikev2 remote-authentication eap query-identity would use EAP/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 as the peer's ID. Have also found references that says the certificate's DN could be used to match the policy/tunnel-group, however I have not been successful making that work.
Here's the ASA debug for the point where it fails:
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_PROC_ID
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Received valid parameteres in process id
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_CHK_IF_PEER_CERT_NEEDS_TO_BE_FETCHED_FOR_PROF_SEL
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_GET_POLICY_BY_PEERID
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Searching policy based on peer's identity 'VPNGRP' of type 'key ID'
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (143): Failed to locate an item in the database
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_AUTH_FAIL
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Verification of peer's authentication data FAILED
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Sending authentication failure notify
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Notify Payload: AUTHENTICATION_FAILEDIKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Building packet for encryption.

Also, using a Windows native client, the peer identity type that it tries to match is IPv4 address which presents the LAN address of the device adapter (not very helpful). I've tried peer-id-validate nocheck and isakmp identity key-id and auto and does not change the error.
I believe the real issue is that I've reached the limits of my understanding of this configuration and I'm just not able to find any good references that explain how this particular use case may work. I may also be misunderstanding the role of the certificates in this configuration - I had thought that in this case it would replace the use of a pre-shared-key string while continuing to allow local/CHAP credentials to enable access for a specific user... this may be an incorrect assumption too.
Any suggestions or clarifications would be most appreciated.  Thanks!
TL;DR:
Relevant ASA config:
ASA Version 9.12(4)58 
!
hostname host
domain-name foo.local

access-list acl_vpn_split extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set set_aes-256-hmac esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set set_aes-256-hma_trans esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set set_aes-256-hma_trans mode transport

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AESSHA256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-256
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec profile VPNGRP
 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 set trustpoint TP
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite

crypto dynamic-map cdm_vpnclient 10 set ikev1 transform-set set_aes-256-hmac set_aes-256-hma_trans
crypto dynamic-map cdm_vpnclient 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AESSHA256 AES256 AES192
crypto map cm_outside 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic cdm_vpnclient
crypto map cm_outside interface outside

crypto ca trustpoint TP
 enrollment terminal
 subject-name CN=host.foo.local, ...
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain TP
 certificate 02
  ********
  quit
 certificate ca *
  ********
  quit
 
crypto isakmp nat-traversal 30

crypto ikev2 policy 9
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha256
 group 24
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha256
 group 5
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint TP

crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
 
group-policy VPNGRP internal
group-policy VPNGRP attributes
 vpn-idle-timeout none
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 l2tp-ipsec 
 password-storage enable
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value acl_vpn_split
 intercept-dhcp enable

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 address-pool pool_vpn
 authentication-server-group (outside) LOCAL
 default-group-policy VPNGRP
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *
 ikev2 remote-authentication eap query-identity
 ikev2 local-authentication certificate TP
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 authentication ms-chap-v2

tunnel-group VPNGRP type remote-access
tunnel-group VPNGRP general-attributes
 address-pool pool_vpn
 authentication-server-group (outside) LOCAL
 default-group-policy VPNGRP
tunnel-group VPNGRP ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *
 ikev2 remote-authentication eap query-identity
 ikev2 local-authentication certificate TP

username user password * nt-encrypted
username user2 password * encrypted

Complete ASA debug:
IKEv2-PROTO-4: Received Packet [From 100.100.100.100:3316/To 200.200.200.200:500/VRF i0:f0]
Initiator SPI : 324F9A17F65A53FE - Responder SPI : 0000000000000000 Message id: 0
IKEv2 IKE_SA_INIT Exchange REQUESTIKEv2-PROTO-5: Next payload: SA, version: 2.0 Exchange type: IKE_SA_INIT, flags: INITIATOR Message id: 0, length: 652
Payload contents:
 SA  Next payload: KE, reserved: 0x0, length: 244
  last proposal: 0x2, reserved: 0x0, length: 136
  Proposal: 1, Protocol id: IKE, SPI size: 0, #trans: 15    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-CBC
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-CBC
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA512
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA384
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA256
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA96
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA512
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA384
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA256
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA1
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_2048_MODP_256_PRIME/Group 24
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_384_ECP/Group 20
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_256_ECP/Group 19
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_2048_MODP/Group 14
    last transform: 0x0, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_1536_MODP/Group 5
  last proposal: 0x0, reserved: 0x0, length: 104
  Proposal: 2, Protocol id: IKE, SPI size: 0, #trans: 11    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-GCM
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-GCM
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA512
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA384
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA256
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA1
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_2048_MODP_256_PRIME/Group 24
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_384_ECP/Group 20
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_256_ECP/Group 19
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_2048_MODP/Group 14
    last transform: 0x0, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_1536_MODP/Group 5
 KE  Next payload: N, reserved: 0x0, length: 264
    DH group: 24, Reserved: 0x0

     28 6b 52 84 a9 50 f8 6e d2 fa 81 f7 3a d5 9a c8
<SNIP>
     d4 af 3b a4 e6 78 91 4e 60 64 8a 45 9b 36 46 e3
 N  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 36

     4c 21 c2 5d 36 15 f2 7c 80 4e c8 42 96 eb 30 41
     5c 60 1f dd 4b 6e 6e 82 2b 9d aa 73 68 32 bb 6c
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 28
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP

     c3 a2 2b 52 02 39 ed c4 d5 14 96 72 ce 1c eb 73
     97 d4 02 11
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 28
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP

     ad 5c fb 61 2c 9c 3f 94 0a b2 7f 7e da cc 70 7c
     bc e1 58 e5
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: Unknown - 16431 NOTIFY(Unknown - 16431)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 16
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: Unknown - 0

     00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: REDIRECT_SUPPORTED NOTIFY(REDIRECT_SUPPORTED)  Next payload: NONE, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: REDIRECT_SUPPORTED

Decrypted packet:Data: 652 bytes
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: IDLE Event: EV_RECV_INIT
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Checking NAT discovery
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: IDLE Event: EV_CHK_REDIRECT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Redirect check is not needed, skipping it
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: IDLE Event: EV_CHK_CAC
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: IDLE Event: EV_CHK_COOKIE
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: IDLE Event: EV_CHK4_COOKIE_NOTIFY
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_VERIFY_MSG
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Verify SA init message
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_INSERT_SA
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Insert SA
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_GET_IKE_POLICY
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_PROC_MSG
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Processing IKE_SA_INIT message
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_DETECT_NAT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Process NAT discovery notify
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Processing nat detect src notify
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Remote address not matched
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Processing nat detect dst notify
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Local address matched
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Host is located NAT outside
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_INIT Event: EV_CHK_CONFIG_MODE
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_SET_POLICY
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Setting configured policies
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_CHK_AUTH4PKI
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_PKI_SESH_OPEN
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Opening a PKI session
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_GEN_DH_KEY
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): [IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Computing DH public key, DH Group 24
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Request queued for computation of DH key
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_NO_EVENT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_OK_RECD_DH_PUBKEY_RESP
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Action: Action_Null
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_GEN_DH_SECRET
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): [IKEv2 -> Crypto Engine] Computing DH secret key, DH Group 24
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Request queued for computation of DH secret
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_NO_EVENT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_OK_RECD_DH_SECRET_RESP
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Action: Action_Null
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_GEN_SKEYID
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Generate skeyid
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_GET_CONFIG_MODE
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_BLD_INIT Event: EV_BLD_MSG
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Generating IKE_SA_INIT message
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): IKE Proposal: 1, SPI size: 0 (initial negotiation),
Num. transforms: 4
(143):    AES-CBC(143):    SHA1(143):    SHA256(143):    DH_GROUP_2048_MODP_256_PRIME/Group 24IKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Vendor Specific Payload: DELETE-REASONIKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Vendor Specific Payload: (CUSTOM)IKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Notify Payload: NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IPIKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Notify Payload: NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IPIKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Notify Payload: IKEV2_FRAGMENTATION_SUPPORTEDIKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Vendor Specific Payload: FRAGMENTATION(143):
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Sending Packet [To 100.100.100.100:3316/From 200.200.200.200:500/VRF i0:f0]
(143): Initiator SPI : 324F9A17F65A53FE - Responder SPI : 80B091E1278E373F Message id: 0
(143): IKEv2 IKE_SA_INIT Exchange RESPONSEIKEv2-PROTO-5: (143): Next payload: SA, version: 2.0 (143): Exchange type: IKE_SA_INIT, flags: RESPONDER MSG-RESPONSE (143): Message id: 0, length: 599(143):
Payload contents:
(143):  SA(143):   Next payload: KE, reserved: 0x0, length: 48
(143):   last proposal: 0x0, reserved: 0x0, length: 44
  Proposal: 1, Protocol id: IKE, SPI size: 0, #trans: 4(143):     last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-CBC
(143):     last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 2, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA1
(143):     last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA256
(143):     last transform: 0x0, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 4, reserved: 0x0, id: DH_GROUP_2048_MODP_256_PRIME/Group 24
(143):  KE(143):   Next payload: N, reserved: 0x0, length: 264
(143):     DH group: 24, Reserved: 0x0
(143):
(143):      38 34 e5 68 3d fd b0 24 d8 04 01 e9 44 7e 13 02
<SNIP>
(143):      35 95 24 e7 9f 66 d8 b3 27 69 4f 2c 14 a3 d2 27
(143):      f7 84 14 a6 fb 26 ad 6f de 17 1b 85 f4 5d 62 a1
(143):  N(143):   Next payload: VID, reserved: 0x0, length: 68
(143):
(143):  VID(143):   Next payload: VID, reserved: 0x0, length: 23
(143):
(143):      43 49 53 43 4f 2d 44 45 4c 45 54 45 2d 52 45 41
(143):      53 4f 4e
(143):  VID(143):   Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 59
(143):
(143):      43 49 53 43 4f 28 43 4f 50 59 52 49 47 48 54 29
<SNIP>
(143):  NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP)(143):   Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 28
(143):     Security protocol id: IKE, spi size: 0, type: NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP
(143):
(143):      e1 01 3d b1 46 f4 da 9c 34 97 15 7e 8e 23 a5 0c
(143):      76 cf 0a 75
(143):  NOTIFY(NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP)(143):   Next payload: CERTREQ, reserved: 0x0, length: 28
(143):     Security protocol id: IKE, spi size: 0, type: NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP
(143):
(143):      fe d5 1f 3b 6e f2 ed 39 46 84 02 b1 ed 95 ab 6b
(143):      7a fc d3 15
(143):  CERTREQ(143):   Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 25
(143):     Cert encoding X.509 Certificate - signature
(143): CertReq data: 20 bytes
(143):  NOTIFY(IKEV2_FRAGMENTATION_SUPPORTED)(143):   Next payload: VID, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
(143):     Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: IKEV2_FRAGMENTATION_SUPPORTED
(143):  VID(143):   Next payload: NONE, reserved: 0x0, length: 20
(143):
(143):      40 48 b7 d5 6e bc e8 85 25 e7 de 7f 00 d6 c2 d3
(143):
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: INIT_DONE Event: EV_DONE
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Completed SA init exchange
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: INIT_DONE Event: EV_CHK4_ROLE
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: INIT_DONE Event: EV_START_TMR
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Starting timer (30 sec) to wait for auth message
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000000 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_NO_EVENT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Request has mess_id 1; expected 1 through 1

(143):
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Received Packet [From 100.100.100.100:3318/To 200.200.200.200:500/VRF i0:f0]
(143): Initiator SPI : 324F9A17F65A53FE - Responder SPI : 80B091E1278E373F Message id: 1
(143): IKEv2 IKE_AUTH Exchange REQUESTIKEv2-PROTO-5: (143): Next payload: ENCR, version: 2.0 (143): Exchange type: IKE_AUTH, flags: INITIATOR (143): Message id: 1, length: 368(143):
Payload contents:
IKEv2-PROTO-4: decrypt queued(143):
(143): Decrypted packet:(143): Data: 368 bytes
(143): REAL Decrypted packet:(143): Data: 299 bytes
 IDi  Next payload: CERTREQ, reserved: 0x0, length: 14
    Id type: key ID, Reserved: 0x0 0x0

     70 74 6e 6f 69 72
 CERTREQ  Next payload: CFG, reserved: 0x0, length: 25
    Cert encoding X.509 Certificate - signature
CertReq data: 20 bytes
 CFG  Next payload: SA, reserved: 0x0, length: 16
    cfg type: CFG_REQUEST, reserved: 0x0, reserved: 0x0

   attrib type: internal IP4 address, length: 0

   attrib type: internal IP4 DNS, length: 0

 SA  Next payload: TSi, reserved: 0x0, length: 124
  last proposal: 0x2, reserved: 0x0, length: 44
  Proposal: 1, Protocol id: ESP, SPI size: 4, #trans: 3    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-GCM
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-GCM
    last transform: 0x0, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 5, reserved: 0x0, id: Don't use ESN
  last proposal: 0x0, reserved: 0x0, length: 76
  Proposal: 2, Protocol id: ESP, SPI size: 4, #trans: 7    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-CBC
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 12
    type: 1, reserved: 0x0, id: AES-CBC
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA512
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA384
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA256
    last transform: 0x3, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 3, reserved: 0x0, id: SHA96
    last transform: 0x0, reserved: 0x0: length: 8
    type: 5, reserved: 0x0, id: Don't use ESN
 TSi  Next payload: TSr, reserved: 0x0, length: 24
    Num of TSs: 1, reserved 0x0, reserved 0x0
    TS type: TS_IPV4_ADDR_RANGE, proto id: 0, length: 16
    start port: 0, end port: 65535
    start addr: 0.0.0.0, end addr: 255.255.255.255
 TSr  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 24
    Num of TSs: 1, reserved 0x0, reserved 0x0
    TS type: TS_IPV4_ADDR_RANGE, proto id: 0, length: 16
    start port: 0, end port: 65535
    start addr: 0.0.0.0, end addr: 255.255.255.255
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: MOBIKE_SUPPORTED NOTIFY(MOBIKE_SUPPORTED)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: MOBIKE_SUPPORTED
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS NOTIFY(ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 24
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS

     26 00 10 09 11 10 c4 d0 00 00 00 00 63 b2 fa 7d
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS NOTIFY(ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 24
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: ADDITIONAL_IPV6_ADDRESS

     26 00 10 09 b1 87 18 f6 05 d9 4c e6 04 fb 59 56
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: Unknown - 16417 NOTIFY(Unknown - 16417)  Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: Unknown - 0
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Parse Notify Payload: Unknown - 16420 NOTIFY(Unknown - 16420)  Next payload: NONE, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: Unknown - 0

IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_RECV_AUTH
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Stopping timer to wait for auth message
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_CHK_NAT_T
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Checking NAT discovery
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): NAT OUTSIDE found
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_CHG_NAT_T_PORT
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): NAT detected float to init port 3318, resp port 4500
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_PROC_ID
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Received valid parameteres in process id
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_CHK_IF_PEER_CERT_NEEDS_TO_BE_FETCHED_FOR_PROF_SEL
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_WAIT_AUTH Event: EV_GET_POLICY_BY_PEERID
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Searching policy based on peer's identity 'VPNGRP' of type 'key ID'
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (143): Failed to locate an item in the database
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_AUTH_FAIL
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Verification of peer's authentication data FAILED
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Sending authentication failure notify
IKEv2-PROTO-7: Construct Notify Payload: AUTHENTICATION_FAILEDIKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Building packet for encryption.
(143):
Payload contents:
(143):  NOTIFY(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)(143):   Next payload: NONE, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
(143):     Security protocol id: IKE, spi size: 0, type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_ENCRYPT_MSG
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_NO_EVENT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_OK_ENCRYPT_RESP
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): Action: Action_Null
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: R_VERIFY_AUTH Event: EV_TRYSEND
(143):
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Sending Packet [To 100.100.100.100:3318/From 200.200.200.200:4500/VRF i0:f0]
(143): Initiator SPI : 324F9A17F65A53FE - Responder SPI : 80B091E1278E373F Message id: 1
(143): IKEv2 IKE_AUTH Exchange RESPONSEIKEv2-PROTO-5: (143): Next payload: ENCR, version: 2.0 (143): Exchange type: IKE_AUTH, flags: RESPONDER MSG-RESPONSE (143): Message id: 1, length: 80(143):
Payload contents:
(143):  ENCR(143):   Next payload: NOTIFY, reserved: 0x0, length: 52
(143): Encrypted data: 48 bytes
(143):
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: AUTH_DONE Event: EV_FAIL
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Auth exchange failed
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (143): Auth exchange failed
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (143): Auth exchange failed
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: EXIT Event: EV_ABORT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: EXIT Event: EV_CHK_PENDING_ABORT
IKEv2-PROTO-7: (143): SM Trace-> SA: I_SPI=324F9A17F65A53FE R_SPI=80B091E1278E373F (R) MsgID = 00000001 CurState: EXIT Event: EV_UPDATE_CAC_STATS
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Abort exchange
IKEv2-PROTO-4: (143): Deleting SA

In above, 100.100.100.100 is client, 200.200.200.200 is ASA.
